# Identifying local processes and associated ports with python

Tags: python, shell

Does python or any linux/unix languages have a library which allows it to find ports available on the localhost based on processes name?

I would like to identify all associated ports with the service name `ssh`.

`lsof`, `netstat` `ps` or `grep` don't seem the most efficient options.

Comment: You can try subprocess module. This is used to run commands on terminal and probably to read output also. You can use grep.

Comment: What OS are you using? if Linux then `nestat -tulp | grep ssh` will do the trick. Then you can use the `subprocess` module as suggested to run this command and process its output.

Answer (score 0):

This got me what I needed, thank you.

```
ss -l -p -n | grep ",pid=`pgrep ssh`," | grep ::: | cut -d : -f 4
```